# Show that a Kernel of a natural mapping in normal groups is the intersection of these.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I've got the following exercise extracted from Rotman's Introduction to Theory of Groups:
Let $H_1, \dots , H_n $ the normal sub groups of $G$, we define $\phi : G \rightarrow G/H_1 \times \dots \times G/H_n$ like  $$\phi(x) = (xH_1, \dots , xH_n)$$ show that $ker(\phi) = H_1 \cap \dots \cap H_n$.

Well we know that the trivial group is part of the kernel and the intersection as well, but I cannot guarantee that is the whole intersection. So any hints?

Comment: Let $x\in ker(\phi)$. Then $x \in H_1, H_2...$. Can you show that?

Comment: Suppose $x \in H_1\cap H_2\cap \cdots\cap H_n$ what is $\phi(x)$?  Suppose it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps:

1) To show $Ker(\phi)\subseteq\cap_{i=1}^n H_i$

> Let $x\in Ker(\phi)$, then $\phi(x)=(xH_1,\dots,xH_n)=(1H_1,\dots,1H_n)$ so $x\in H_i$ for each $i=1,\dots n$ so $Ker(\phi)\subseteq\cap_{i=1}^n H_i$.

2) To show $\cap_{i=1}^n H_i \subseteq Ker(\phi)$

> Now let $y \in \cap_{i=1}^n H_i$, then $\phi(y)=(yH_1,\dots,yH_n)$ but $y\in H_i$ so $yH_i=1H_i$ thus $\phi(y)=(1H_1,\dots,1H_n)$ and we conclude $y\in Ker(\phi)$.  In particular $\cap_{i=1}^n H_i \subseteq Ker(\phi)$.

So we can conclude $Ker(\phi)=\cap_{i=1}^n H_i$.

Comment: I solved it a few hours before your answer, following the ideas in the comments, but is it valid anyway. So, thanks.